# IIS 6.0 renders HTML page properly but gives error while serving .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I have an app built in `ASP.NET/C#`.

I have created a WebSetUp for the application.The setup installation was successful.
It also created the virtual directory `Cwiz` which I mentioned during installation.

I also enabled `ASP.NET` in `IIS 6.0`.
Now when I try to access the page like localhost/Cwiz/Login.aspx It gives me an error

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /HomeLogin.aspx
```

When I try to access a html page like `localhost/Cwiz/test.html` it works properly.

I am using `Forms Authentication`.

I have searched for the solution enough but can't seem to guess what can be wrong.I enabled `ASP.NET` in `IIS`.

Can anyone help me with this issue.
Any suggestion are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear, the `/HomeLogin.aspx` does not exists, make sure to add the appropiate url in the web.config file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/HomeLogin.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

You are being redirected to this file because you have not been authenticated with the server

BTW you commented:

> Now when I try to access the page like localhost/Cwiz/Login.aspx It gives me an error

But your error contains:

> Requested URL: /HomeLogin.aspx

The login pages are different, perhaps that's the problem

Comment: It is HomeLogin.aspx and not Login.aspx , so should I try to include that in my web.config file.Thanks.

Comment: yep, and try accessing another page, let's say `default.aspx`

Comment: I tried accessing default.aspx and now I get this error http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Login+failed+for+user+'NT+AUTHORITY%5CNETWORK+SERVICE'.&oq=Login+failed+for+user+'NT+AUTHORITY%5CNETWORK+SERVICE'.&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.996.996.0.1299.1.1.0.0.0.0.190.190.0j1.1.0...0.0.ZtBi3aUWFNs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d70cb7a1447ca32b&biw=1024&bih=677

Comment: +1 for rectifying my missing thing , however I already had it in the config file initially it was <forms loginUrl="/HomeLogin.aspx" timeout="2880" /> and I changed it to <forms loginUrl="~/HomeLogin.aspx" timeout="2880" /> and it worked.Thanks a lot mate.I was hunting for this for last 2 days.